# Select the row with the max value from a table where sum is calculated

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I'm trying to find out how can I extract the rows with the highest value on Suma column from a table which I did with this script:

```
SELECT specializare, 
       Count(codprocedura) AS NrProceduri, 
       Sum(pret)           AS Suma 
FROM   (SELECT p.pret                AS Pret, 
               fp.specializaredoctor AS Specializare, 
               fp.codprocedura       AS CodProcedura 
        FROM   proceduri p 
               INNER JOIN fisepacienti fp 
                       ON fp.codpacienti = p.codproc)intermediar 
GROUP  BY intermediar.specializare
```

The DB tables can be created with this:

create table Pacienti(
    CodP int not null primary key,
    Nume varchar(50),
    Prenume varchar(50),
    Descriere varchar(50),
    Varsta int,
    DataNasterii varchar(50)

);

create table Proceduri(
    CodProc int not null primary key,
    Nume varchar(50),
    Descriere varchar(50),
    Pret int

);

create table FisePacienti(
    PRIMARY KEY(CodPacienti, CodProcedura),
    CodPacienti int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pacienti(CodP),
    CodProcedura int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Proceduri(CodProc),
    Data varchar(50),
    NumeDoctor varchar(50),
    PrenumeDoctor varchar(50),
    SpecializareDoctor varchar(50),
    VechimeDoctor varchar(50)

);

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES fp.specializare, 
       Count(fp.codprocedura) AS NrProceduri, 
       Sum(p.pret) AS Suma
FROM proceduri p JOIN
     fisepacienti fp 
     ON fp.codpacienti = p.codproc
GROUP BY fp.specializare 
ORDER BY SumA DESC;
```

Note that a subquery is not needed for the aggregation.

Comment: Gordon, thanks a lot! I didn't have any idea that I can use TOP() with this function " WITH TIES". It saves lives. I used initially only TOP(1) but it has not covered all the cases requested.